# Permissions required for a local user to query services

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, service

I'm trying to write an application, that is running as a local user on the server, and needs access to enumerate services, and potentially even control them (start/stop).

Is being a part of the administrators group the *only* way this user would be able to get access to this functionality (being used via the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class)? If easier, I'd be ok with even just being able to enumerate the list of services (the interactive starting/stopping isn't a show-stopper). Would adding the user to the power user's group work?

Thanks!

edit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981(v=vs.85).aspx#access_rights_for_the_service_control_manager

Answer (score 6):

The Power Users group is never the answer. It's an old legacy thing. Best to just consider it non-existent.

If you want to set permissions on individual Windows services in a granular way, you can, but it's nowhere near as easy/intuitive as setting permissions on a file

To view the current permissions of a Windows service:

```
C:\Users\Ryan>sc sdshow netlogon

D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCR
RC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)
```

To set the permissions on a single Windows service, for example, so that a non-admin user can start and stop a particular service:

```
sc sdset netlogon "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;RPWPCR;;;S-1-5-21-2103278432-2794320136-1883075150-1000)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)"
[SC] SetServiceObjectSecurity SUCCESS
```

That looks awful, doesn't it?  That goo is called SDDL - Security Descriptor Definition Language.

[This article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/erikr/archive/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows.aspx) is a pretty good primer on how to interpret SDDL and do what you're trying to do.

You can also use Security Templates and Group Policies to accomplish the same thing:

[image: Security Template]

Comment: The subinacl commandline tool, available as a server 2003 reskit download, is also an option. It uses a not-quite-so-messy syntax to edit service permissions. I'll post a syntax for reference in tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

Another friendly option for doing the same thing is the subinacl command line tool included in the Windows 2003 Resource Kit. It is a wonderful little bag of tricks.

Here is the syntax for setting user permissions on services:

```
SUBINACL /SERVICE \\MachineName\ServiceName /GRANT=[DomainName\]UserName[=Access]
```

These are the Access-options available:

```
F : Full Control
R : Generic Read
W : Generic Write
X : Generic eXecute
L : Read controL
Q : Query Service Configuration
S : Query Service Status
E : Enumerate Dependent Services
C : Service Change Configuration
T : Start Service
O : Stop Service
P : Pause/Continue Service
I : Interrogate Service 
U : Service User-Defined Control Commands
```

So to give the members of the group DOMAIN\GroupName permission to start and stop the service 'ServiceName' one would:

```
subinacl /service ServiceName /GRANT=DOMAIN\GroupName=TO
```

To view permissions set on the service 'ServiceName' (before and after running the above) one would:

```
subinacl.exe /service /verbose=1 ServiceName
```

Here is an official HOWTO for setting service permissions using subinacl:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288129

And here is the subinacl download link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510

Comment: Subinacl is at least more friendly that sc sdset. Have an upvote.

Comment: does it work on Server 2012 / 2012 R2, too? As far as i can see, Microsoft doesn't officially list it as compatible.

Answer (score 3):

To enumerate services, your process needs the `SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE` right, in the old days every authenticated user had this right, but since Vista this is no longer the case.

Interactive users have it, that's why a normal user can do a `net start` or `Get-Service`

You can change the permissions on the Service Control Manager to allow your process to enumerate services. You also need to change permissions on any service you want to access.

I just wrote a [blog post](https://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/post/2013/11/23/Accessing-service-status-from-a-scheduled-task) about how to do this, it includes a PowerShell script to do this for all services on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, that all depends on the language you're using to query processes, but the required user role will be determined by a set of privileges that your code will need on the target machine.
Some of those privileges are associated with normal user accounts whereas others will require admin role.